# any delegate call when watch app disconnect to app?

Tags: bluetooth, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to check below senerio in watch app for disconnection and connection to app,

1. Disable bluetooth
2. Disable WIFI
3. Watch app out of range
4. Coonected to bluetooth
5. Watch app available in range

In above five case, apple call any delegate method to watch app, so we can handle it?

Any session state change delegate method call in watch app?

Answer (score 0):

yes there are delegates for these in `WCSessionDelgate` protocol, you can use

```
- (void)sessionWatchStateDidChange:(WCSession *)session
```

and

```
- (void)sessionReachabilityDidChange:(WCSession *)session;
```

to find the reachability and state change of the connected watch

Comment: I want to check in Apple watch app not in iPhone app. This API only use in iPhone app.

Comment: `sessionReachabilityDidChange` is available for both watch and iphone. thats saysle and parent app is running whether the iphone is reachbab

Comment: it's not working for me, i have disable bluetooth and check but no luck.